# How will location apps work in Android O?

Tags: android, background, location, android-8.0-oreo

Right now many apps track your location. However, in Android Oreo, "apps will not be able to freely run in the background" as stated in [this Android Developers video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc).

According to [the developer docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/o/background-location-limits.html),

> Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour.

And for any exceptions to that rule:

> Consider whether your app's use cases for running in the background cannot succeed at all if your app receives infrequent location updates. If this is the case, you can retrieve location updates more frequently by performing one of the following actions:
>
> ...
>
> Start a foreground service in your app by calling startForegroundService(). When such a foreground service is active, it appears as an ongoing notification in the notification area.

**What this seems to be saying is, if you're a user of a location tracking on Oreo, you're stuck with yet another ongoing notification at all times. Is this correct?**

I really hope there's a way around this because if I have three apps that track location, my notification bar is going to be cluttered with three ongoing notifications even when I'm not moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What this seems to be saying is, if you want to be able to detect location changes in Oreo, your app requires an ongoing notification at all times. Is this correct?

Not exactly. It is saying that apps that want to receive location updates more frequently than a few times an hour, while not being the foreground activity, will most likely need to create a foreground service. As the docs indicate, there are alternatives (passive provider, geofencing, batched API). And some apps will not need location updates especially frequently, because the underlying data does not change especially frequently (e.g., a weather app widget).

> if I have three apps that track location, my notification bar is going to be cluttered with three ongoing notifications even when I'm not moving

IMHO, if you have 1+ apps that continuously track your location in the background, you really need to reconsider your life choices.

Comment: First off, I'm honored to receive an answer from CommonsWare! Huge fan of your books and stackoverflow answers! 2. In order to detect location changes, an app needs continuous access to location, no? 3. The other options in the docs (passive provider, geofencing, batched API) don't provide frequent enough updates for tracking location as far as I can tell. 4. Currently in the process of reevaluating haha. But there are a lot of users who use (probably 1) location tracking apps. Are they stuck with yet another ongoing notification? 5. Edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Patrick: "In order to detect location changes, an app needs continuous access to location, no?" -- again, it depends on the app's needs. Weather forecasts change slowly, so only getting a location a few times an hour would be OK. "Are they stuck with yet another ongoing notification?" -- most likely, at least at first. Frankly, simply having *code* running in the background on Android 8.0+ is a problem without a foreground service. I haven't experimented to see what happens if the user suppresses the notification, though. Android might still deliver frequent location updates in that scenario.

Comment: @Patrick: "But there are a lot of users who use (probably 1) location tracking apps" -- undoubtedly. Given the security issues of Android devices and the propensity for servers to get hacked, I recommend using locations as little as possible, particularly continuously in the background. BTW, thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like the answer is "most likely, at least at first." Accepting this as the answer assuming you're answering based on the documentation above (though would love any additional explanation if based off other reasoning as well).